# New RAM memory not working

Tags: boot, memory

I have bought a new RAM memory stick for my computer. The model is **Kingston ValueRAM DDR3 1333 PC3-10600 4GB CL9**. I have put in my computer which has an **Asus P7H55-M** motherboard. Apparently, they should be compatible (I read that in the seller's website's Q&A).

However, when I start my computer, after the BIOS recognises the 4 GB memory, the Windows starting screen appears but suddenly the computer restarts. It is always the same: the OS appears for just a few seconds, showing different screens (Windows 10 loading, Windows 10 repairing, blue screen...).

I have tried with the new memory stick alone (without the memory sticks I had previously), which I guess is the best way to avoid incompatibility problems, but it doesn't neither work together with one or the two 2 GB memory sticks I owned before (they work, either together or alone).

Is this a BIOS/Windows configuration problem or my motherboard won't accept this new memory?

**UPDATE:**
I tried with Memtest86 and it worked perfect with my 2 old memory sticks. However, when running it with my new memory stick, it freezed after a few seconds, when first test was running 14%. After rebooting, I couldn't load from my USB drive (in which Memtest86 is located). After unplugging and switching on again, I run Memtest86 with exactly the same results: it freeezed at the same point.

[image: Screnshot]

I expected Memtest86 either to end without problems or to show an error, not to crash. Is the memory broken or is it something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be a damaged stick of RAM...

Comment: I would suggest you try running some checks on the RAM stick alone using something like [Memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) or [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org).

Comment: I tried Memtest86 with unexpected results. I updated my question explaining what happened.

Comment: Make sure all your BIOS settings relating to memory timings and voltages are set to their defaults.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They seem to be... never changed anything unusual from the BIOS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, seeing that Memtest86 wouldn't finish, I returned the memory stick to the shop and they confirmed me that it was broken. Sometimes the [easiest explanation is the right one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).